# Can 你去吧 be considered rude and what are some alternatives?

Tags: grammar, verbs, politeness, formal

For example, if your classmate says he has to get home soon before it starts raining, and you want to support his decision, can you say  “你去吧” ？In English one could say "Go, go!" But obviously this is very informal and only used with friends.

I feel that this phrase can also have a negative connotation, like "get out of my sight". Is this true?

Are there any better phrases, or those that can be used in a less casual context? I.e. something like "go ahead" or "you'd better get going then".

Anyone have some clarification?

Answer (score 6):

The alternative will be “你快(點)回去吧”, or simply "快回去".

Depending on the situation, “你去吧” can be seen as cold, arrogant, or rude. Worst of all, it is a phrase frequently used during the funeral "(Bye), go ahead". :)

Answer (score 3):

> I feel that this phrase can also have a negative connotation, like "get out of my sight". Is this true?

Not at all, you can safely consider it as "Go ahead" in English. There might be cold or absentmindedness or at most carelessness, but definitely not rudeness.

Another phase **快滚吧** expresses rudeness or hatred, and it also can be used joyfully between intimate friends.

Answer (score 3):

你去吧 usually means "You can go back and continue what you are doing before you came to me".

Safe usages of "你去吧" if you are:

1. Boss when talking to your employee
2. Teacher when talking to your student
3. Parent when talking to your child
   ...

For your particular circumstance, it's not rude to say this to your friend, but it's a little cold.

The following would be better in your situation:

```
A: 快下雨了，我该早点回去了
B: 行，快回去吧！
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a phrase 去忙 something like: go do your stuff!

A: 我还有点事。
B: 没关系，你去忙吧！